# Inheritance of method not working when changing views

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am defining a method "onClick" in a widget called main, and then i define, in another component (reportsview) the following method to go from it back to the main view :

```
onMainView: function() {
        
        var reportsViewInstance = Ext.getCmp('reportsview');
        
        if (reportsViewInstance) {
            reportsViewInstance.destroy();
            
        }

        var mainV2 = Ext.create('widget.main', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            hideMode: 'visibility'
        });

        mainV2.show();
        

    }
```

When the above method is called (e.g in the main view) i expect that the onClick method is callable (because it is defined in the controller of the main) but instead i get an error saying : No method named "onClick" on Class.view.ReportController (which is where the reportsview is defined). I tried with the following in the Class.view.ReportController :

```
requires: [

        'Class.view.MainController'
    ],
```

The main view is defined as :

```
Ext.define('Class.view.Main', {
       extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
       alias: 'widget.main',
       id: 'mainView',
       xtype: 'mainV',
       reference: 'mainViewRef',
      

       controller: 'mainController', ...
```

In the the mainController i have defined the onClick method which is normally callable when the current view is main but in the above code onClick gives the mentioned error.

Comment: What about fiddle sample?

Comment: I don't have a sencha account to make a fiddle

Comment: AFAIK you can open one here https://forum.sencha.com/forum/register.php

Comment: I don't have the full code right now in front of me : but i have prepared rapidly the sample at : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aum

Comment: You sample does not work. You don't need to present all your project, just very small sample which will describe the issue.

Comment: Please see this fiddle :fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aup it's not working but you got all the code i'm using . what i want to know is if it the correct way of switching views. thanks

Comment: I suggest you read the view_controller docs https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/guides/application_architecture/view_controllers.html  look for control: in that document.  it explains how you control (or listen) for events on child views.

Comment: @mcg1103 thanks ! i just used `extend `for the inheritance to work!